# tableview cell needs to reset core data entities when deleted

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, delegates

in my swift code below when one tableview cell is deleted the tableview cells after is not showing a change in the place of the number. So when 2 is deleted what is left is 1 and 3 it should just state 1 and 2. I listed my code below with the delete function.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let title = itemName[indexPath.row]
    let cell = theScores.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for : indexPath)
   
    cell.selectionStyle = .default

    

    if let position = title.value(forKey: "positon") {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Item : \(title.positon))"
    }
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Item: \(title.positon)"
    
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    
    
    return cell
    
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemName.count
    
    
}
     var itemName : [Player] = []
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
        let appd = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appd.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        context.delete(itemName[indexPath.row])
        itemName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch {
            print("d")
        }
        self.theScores.reloadData()
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the code of cellForRow?

Comment: please post code for cellFor indexPath method

Comment: @Larme added code

Comment: @SPatel added code

Comment: Initially your core data has Item1, Item2, Item3. When you delete Item2, you are no updating your data to change Item3 to Item2 so it's title remains the same. I think after a deletion has taken place, the positions of all the data after it has to be reordered. Without that, don't you think the positions would still be the same or am I missing something?

Comment: What is `position` A property you set yourself? If yes, instead of `position`, imagine it being a name: Luffy, Zoro & Sanji. if you remove Zoro, the third item named Sanji have to be renamed Zoro?